# Get user's ids to a list from guild discord.py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

Is it possible to get all of the members's user ids from a guild (server)?

Edit: I can't use guild, because I need to get the ids when the bot gets online (on_ready)

Comment: Please add some draft of code so SO can help find the issues.

Comment: [Welcome to StackOverflow.](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) Yes, it's possible to get the IDs of all members in a guild. You have to write code for that. Is that your full question? Please [edit] your question to include code/clarify the problem you're facing.

Answer (score 0):

code snippet from discordpy.readthedocs.io:

```
async for member in guild.fetch_members(limit=None):
    print(member.id)
# modded a bit to set no limit and attain userid as asked in question
```

ref: https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Guild.fetch_members

Answer (score 0):

You said you wanted to get the member's IDs on_ready in your edit. Down below is a way to get the member ids of everyone from a guild. You alter what you do with `member.id` if needed I guess.

```py
async def on_ready():
    for guild in bot.guilds():
        for member in guild:
            print (member.id)
```

As mentioned above by other users, SO is a place to help refractor code or help with errors within pre-existing code, so keep that in mind for next time.